# how to include different data templates under a single content control ,

Tags: wpf, xaml

The requirement is to load  different views(data grid) on selection of radiobuttons.We have created a DataTemplate which internally changes the nested datatemplated for the content presenter.

Main DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SchedulesItemTemplate">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="SchedulePresenter"
                          Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NewSchedulesTemplate}"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataContext.ElementView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                         Value="{x:Static Local:Element.NewSchedules}">
                <Setter TargetName="SchedulePresenter" 
                        Property="ContentTemplate" 
                        Value="{StaticResource NewSchedulesTemplate}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataContext.ElementView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                         Value="{x:Static Local:Element.DuplicateSchedules}">
                <Setter TargetName="SchedulePresenter" 
                        Property="ContentTemplate" 
                        Value="{StaticResource DuplicateSchedulesTemplate}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataContext.ElementView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                         Value="{x:Static Local:Element.ExpiredSchedules}">
                <Setter TargetName="SchedulePresenter" 
                        Property="ContentTemplate" 
                        Value="{StaticResource ExpiredSchedulesTemplate}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The nested datatemplate will be like this, with different set of columns :

Now I need to pass a common item source to the main data template and only specify the specific columns to be displayed in datagrid. Something like :
 -->

```
    <ContentControl Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"                          
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SchedulesItem
```

Comment: Is this WPF or WinRT? They're two different platforms. It looks like WPF based on `{x:Static...}`.

Comment: Also, it looks like your last example section got cut off a bit.

Comment: Its is wpf related, i can paste the whole source code (Xaml)